# Pinch to zoom listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

So I am trynna make a widget with pinch to zoom in listview, list view contains: container that contains text. So you can basically pinch in to zoom the whole listview. I have looked into flutter interactive viewer and zoom library but it doesn't seem to be working.

From the following:

[image: From This]

To the following:

[image: To this]

Any thoughts n prayers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead what I ended up doing was setting on-pinch to zoom or zoom-out increase/decrease the size of the text. And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

> You Can pass any widget to this class and can zoom the widget as you can!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart';

class ZoomableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

   const ZoomableWidget({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ZoomableWidgetState createState() => _ZoomableWidgetState();
}

class _ZoomableWidgetState extends State<ZoomableWidget> {
  double _scale = 1.0;
  late double _previousScale;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) {
          _previousScale = _scale;
        },
        onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            _scale = _previousScale * details.scale;
          });
        },
        onScaleEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) {
          _previousScale = 0;
        },
        child: Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.diagonal3(Vector3(_scale.clamp(1.0, 5.0),
              _scale.clamp(1.0, 5.0), _scale.clamp(1.0, 5.0))),
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: widget.child, **add your listview here**
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question, what exactly is the Transform and the ClipRect Widget for? Is it important?

Comment: I mean for a list view just use Sized box and the Flexible Widget?

Answer (score 1):

For this I have 2 solutions, hope it will work for you too.

1. **InteractiveViewer**

[InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) widget supports pan and Zoom out of the box.

To make any widget zoomable you need to simply wrap the child with **InteractiveViewer**.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: InteractiveViewer(
      panEnabled: false, // Set it to false to prevent panning. 
      boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(80),
      minScale: 0.5,
      maxScale: 4, 
      child: FlutterLogo(size: 200),
    ),
  );
}
```

2. [matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector)

A gesture detector package created by @pskink to handle the rotation, scale, and zoom.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

class ZoomableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ZoomableWidget({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ZoomableWidgetState createState() => _ZoomableWidgetState();
}

class _ZoomableWidgetState extends State<ZoomableWidget> {
  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MatrixGestureDetector(
      onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
        setState(() {
          matrix = m;
        });
      },
      child: Transform(
        transform: matrix,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution. I tried the first one, but the issue is that part of the listview goes out of screen as in it's same as when you zoom into pictures. I want it to adjust the length of the container so the whole text is visible.